Text in SnackBar: not selectable for copy/paste
 SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
          showCloseIcon: true,
          duration: 100,
          content: Text('Hello World'),
        );

Text in SnackBar: not selectable for copy/paste by mouse or tap. Is there a way to enable text selection?


Text is not selectable by default.

If you want to make your Text selectable, you need to use SelectableText for that.
 SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
          showCloseIcon: true,
          duration: 100,
          content: SelectableText('Hello World'),
        );

If you want to make an area selectable you can wrap your Widget with SelectionArea.
 SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
          showCloseIcon: true,
          duration: 100,
          content: SelectionArea (
              child: Text('Hello World'),
        );


Try using SelectableText:
SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
  duration: Duration(seconds: 100),
  content: SelectableText('Hello World'),
);

